# Number of rows in a table using Selenium C#

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-ide, selenium-rc

I am new to Selenium. I am working with c#. There is a table like this . I saw it using FireBug.

```
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr class="v-table-row-odd"></tr>
    <tr class="v-table-row"></tr>
    <tr class="v-table-row-odd"></tr>
    <tr class="v-table-row"></tr>
    <tr class="v-table-row-odd"></tr>
    <tr class="v-table-row"></tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

And the issue here is I am not knowing how to get the number of rows in a table which changes dynamically. Is there any way??

Tried xpathCount but got some exception issues..

```
decimal numOfRows = selenium.GetXpathCount("xpath=/html/body/div/div/div[2]/div/div[3]/div/div[2]/div/div/div[2]/div/div/div/div/div[7]/div/div/div[2]/div/table/tbody/tr");
```

I also tried xpathCount like this

```
selenium.GetXpathCount("xpath=/html/body/div/div/div[2]/div/div[3]/div/div[2]/div/div/div[2]/div/div/div/div/div[7]/div/div/div[2]/div/table/tbody");
```

But both  raised exceptions. Can anyone help me out in this regard.

Thank You

Comment: Which exceptions? Chances are you got your xpath expressions wrong.

Comment: Has any div in this xPath got an id or any other unique value of an attribute? If you want to get number of rows, you should use something like the first xPath (ending with /table/tbody/tr) rather than only /table/tbody, because the second will count number of tbody in table - so it will be 1).

Comment: Those are some really lousy XPath selectors.  They'll give you no end of trouble later on when the page structure changes a little bit.  But the real problem you have is that `GetXpathCount()` only works on XPath selectors, so it doesn't expect the selector to begin with `xpath=`.  Remove that and what you've coded will work, at least for now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If it's the only table with rows marked with those class names, you could just use:

```
decimal numOfOddRows = selenium.GetXpathCount("//tr[@class='v-table-row-odd']"); // 3
decimal numOfEvenRows = selenium.GetXpathCount("//tr[@class='v-table-row']");    // 3
decimal numOfRows = numOfOddRows + numOfEvenRows;                        // 3 + 3 = 6
```

If not, then you need to find a better way of locating the `table`.  Something is not quite right with your (very long) XPath selector which starts from the very top of the document.  There's nothing inherently wrong about this, but with a dynamic webpage it is very hard to get right.

Instead, you need to locate an element closer to your `table` and then filter within that.  If for instance, if one of your `div`s has a `name` attribute, you could use `//div[@name='someName']//tr`.  For more information about using XPath selectors, see [here](http://www.w3schools.com/xpath/xpath_syntax.asp).

Comment: It's better to count <tr> inside <tbody> by using int iRowsCount = driver.FindElements(By.XPath("//table/tbody/tr")).Count;

Answer (score 4):

Try this to get the number of Rows in a Table

```
int iRowsCount = driver.FindElements(By.XPath("/html/body/..../table/tbody/tr")).Count;
```

Answer (score 1):

What worked for me was a combination of XPath with ID and the table tbody tr elements added at the end.

```
int RowCount = driver.FindElements(By.XPath("//*[@id='tableID']/tbody/tr")).Count;
```